# Lost partition after trying to run BootCamp on 10.13 on APFS. How to recover?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, high-sierra, apfs

After trying to install Windows via Bootcamp on (yes I understand what "beta" means) beta High Sierra 10.13 I was left with unbootable partition:

[image]

I cannot mount this disk. It's shown as "Mac OS Extended" file system though it was APFS. (The Untitled is the partition with newly installed Mac OS version via internet recover.

```
sudo gpt show disk0
    start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  378644440      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  379054080     262144         
  379316224  109638488      3  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488954712    1280000      4  GPT part - 5361644D-6163-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

I have run two checks.

```
sudo fsck_apfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk0s2
```

Output:
https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/e14156e7db7a1d11c008b1ed78a47cdc

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk0s2
```

Output:
https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/a029f50310eedb2e6664f8652877ec97

I understand that I deal with beta software, and I should not expect to recover lost partition, but nevertheless I would be grateful for suggestion, what to do to recover this partition.

Comment: Apple's solution will be "boot to recovery, wipe everything and set up" but could you elaborate on what "recover"  and "unbeatable" means to you? (you might also add a gist showing `sudo gpt show disk0` and `diskutil list` and optionally `diskutil ap list` in case our volunteer cadre of disk repair wizards show up (cough klanomath, cough).

Comment: @bmike Meant "unbootable". sudo gpt show disk0 : https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/912bfa11d7b54adbb6696d2a43f37dba   diskutil list: https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/ca9e7c93a86849e82e9a4315a8189f24  diskutil ap list: https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/1c528dfddc5376600c983cb4a081eef7   Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK - excellent edit. My knowledge isn't going to help other than to see if you can boot with option key or select the BootCamp volume from the Startup Disk pane - likely those aren't going to work given the data I see, but those steps can't hurt any more than what's done. Also - a bug report or feedback if you have that option with Apple might get an engineer's attention - they are clearly looking for real world breakage at this point in the beta process.